# Issues with exernal monitor on elementary OS Juno

Tags: display, hdmi

Two days ago I installed elementary OS and now I am experiencing issues with my external monitor. I'm using a Dell XPS 15 9560 with and LG superwide monitor.

**Unable to disable built-in monitor**

At the office I like to work on a external monitor with the laptop open and the built-in display disabled. With this setup I can use the track pad of the laptop for scrolling. That's how I did it with the previous distro (Pop!_OS) I've been using. But disabling the built-in monitor seems to be impossible with eOS, or am I wrong?

**No tray nor dock after sleep**

While using an external monitor, my laptop is closed. This works fine s long as the system does not go to sleep. Waking it up is a pain because it does not listen to the wireless mouse or keyboard (also Dell). Touching the built-in keyboard wakes up the system but then I have two screens, both missing the to menu bar/tray as well as the dock. The only thing I can do in this scenario is a hard reboot.

**Not dock nor tray after reboot**

This morning I logged in and again, no tray or dock were showing, so I did a reboot without the external monitor. But even after a reboot, they didn't show up. I had to manually launch the switchbaord (`/usr/bin/io.elementray.switchboard`) though the terminal to be able to access display settings, where I fiddled a bit with the settings. After rebooting the tray and dock were back (fortunately).

Answer (score 2):

I'm facting similar issues on HP Spectre x360. Loki worked great, but Juno is terrible.

In response to **Unable to disable built-in monitor**, I have found a way to turn it off:

1. Find out the display names:

   ```
   xrandr | grep conn | grep -v dis
   ```
2. Disable the desired display:

   ```
   xrandr --output <display> --off
   ```

On my machine, first command returned:

```
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+6 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm
```

Then to switch off the primary laptop built-in display I simply did:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --off
```

I know it is not a solution but it is a start. I am intrigued by your other problems too so it is a scenario that I will be testing next.

Comment: In the meantime I just use the `super + P` combination, every time I need to reboot or re-connect the external display, to disable the built-in monitor. The elementary OS team prioritized this issue since it affects so many users. So I'm sure a fix is in the making.

Comment: For the built in display to be switched off, I'm keeping the command to switch off the built-in display in my `.bashrc` file, so I needn't bother on doing it again and again and it is a good solution!